# Update all schemas with multitenancy architecture

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I have a Java Web project with multitenancy using Hibernate, Spring and JPA. We recently implemented the architecture multitenancy but we don't know how update all the schemas of the database. Before that, when we didn't have this architecture we set in the persistence.xml the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto with update, but now it isn't possible because we have more than one schema. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) instead of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` which shouldn't be used in production anyway. An incremental schema update can provide you a guarantee that the product environment can be safely updated, once you tested the incremented scripts on a QA server.